# Raspbmc windows installer "Does Nothing"

Tags: raspbmc, image, windows

When using **Raspbmc** from the original developers page [Windows Installation](http://www.raspbmc.com/wiki/user/windows-installation/), after finishing with the Windows Installer and following the installation note and also getting **Successful** message, it's the time to put the SD card into the **Raspberry Pi** and boot it with the image written on it which should bring up the installation page on Raspberry Pi.

### What's the issue

**Raspberry Pi** doesn't boot up with whatever is written on it. **RED LED** is the only one turned on(with the possible fainting green) and the HDMI doesn't have signal.
I also checked what's written on SD card and it seems, NOTHING.

So basically *windows installer* DOES download the image file from internet but it DOES NOT write it into the SD card.

SD card isn't an issue, tested with 5 different ones which are already functional.
Raspberry Pi or power to it isn't an issue. It runs Debian, OpenELEC and everything else.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read in the official page: [Windows Installation](http://www.raspbmc.com/wiki/user/windows-installation/), so many people have this problem and they describe it as "Nothing is happening".

First thing to do is to check if the installer wrote anything into your SD card. If not follow these steps.

1. Windows Installer downloads the image required in the folder which
   you have extracted the Windows Installer. The file is called
   **Installer.img.gz**.
2. Extract the contects of this compressed archive using [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).
3. It should be one file inside the extracted archive called **Installer.img*. This is the file you need.
4. Download the [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/?source=typ_redirect) and run it.
5. With the **Win32 Disk Imager** browse to the **Installer.img**, and also select the drive letter for your SD card under **Device** and then press **Write** button.

After write is finished you're done. Now you can put the SD into your Raspberry Pi and run the installation. 
Remember that you need the Ethernet cable with DHCP enabled, connected to Raspberry Pi during the installation to access the internet.